# MongoDB, indexing arrays of ids?

Tags: mongodb, node.js

Using MongoDB...

If I have an array of ids in one field, can I quickly query it for containing id_x?

If so how would I insure and index on it so it is as fast as possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can just build an index on that field. That the key has multiple values makes no difference in how you do that. They call this the [Multikey](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Multikeys) feature.

```
  db.articles.ensureIndex( { tags : 1 } )
```

And the query is the same as well:

```
 db.articles.find( { tags: 'april' } )
```

It just happens to hit any document which has (at least) that tag.

Comment: Can you query for an array of tags too? The reverse scenario? Searching any in an array for a single value in the doc or searching any in an array for any in an array in the doc?

Comment: If you want MATCH_ANY, you can use `$in`. If you want MATCH_ALL, you can use `$all`: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24all If you want to match the array exactly, I am not sure, especially not if order is important, too. That is probably worth another question here.